# place of logging.ini config file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a python project (let's say under `project_dir` directory).

```
project_dir/ ---------- src/ ----------- util.py
             |
             |----- logging.ini
```

Under `project_dir/src`, I have a `util.py`, where the `logger` is defined and logging is configured by calling the config file as:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Here, I call the `logging.ini` with just specifying the file name. And it is working fine. However, the file is directly under `project_dir`, i.e., `project_dir/logging.ini`.

I would like to know why calling 'logging.ini' is working but `../logging.ini` is not? Why I cannot say:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)
```

which gives me error:

```
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'
```

Does it have anything to do with my IDE, which is PyCharm.

Will it be different: run it from PyCharm or run it on a server?

Comment: Because `../logging.ini` is not the same as `logging.ini`. The `..` means *'one directory up in the file hierarchy'*.

Comment: Yes. But I mean it should be `../logging.ini` since `util.py` is at `project_dir/src/util.py` but logging config file is at `project_dir/logging.ini`. `util.py` should call `logging.ini` by going one level up right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your 'current working directory' is not what you think it is.

To get the current working directory use:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```